# Trying (and failing) to implement ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement ActionBarSherlock in my existing application, but I've been having some trouble, so I decided to create a new application and see if I can get it working there.

I create a new android project, I import the ABS library and then I set my new Android project to use the library. To test out if it works, I go to my manifest and I set the theme of my application to `@style/Theme.Sherlock`. I run it on my phone (4.1) and I get the holo theme, but when I run it on my emulator (2.2) I get the text in the middle (Hello World) but no actionbar. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are extending from a `Sherlock`-prefixed activity class. (e.g., `SherlockActivity`, `SherlockFragmentActivity`)

Comment: Ugh... now I know it's late. Time for me to get to bed. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the great repo Jake.